# How to get users who assigned to group

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In my application, Member have permission to manage each task. The way of given permission to member is,
each member is assigned to separate group and each group have separate permission. So the members of each group receive the permission given to the group.

I have following tables structures,

**Group**

```
+---------+------+
| GroupID | Name |
+---------+------+
| G1       | YYY  |
+---------+------+
| G2       | XXX  |
+---------+------+
| G3       | UUU  |
+---------+------+
```

**Authorization**

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
| AuthorizationID | AuthorizationName |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| AUTH1           | Delete            |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| AUTH2           | Send              |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| AUTH3           | ADD               |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

**Memeber**

```
+----------+------+
| MemberID | Name |
+----------+------+
| 1        | PAUL |
+----------+------+
| 2        | JHON |
+----------+------+
| 3        | AMBE |
+----------+------+
| 4        | NISH |
+----------+------+
```

**GroupAuthorization**

```
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| GroupAuthorizationID | FKGroupID | FkAuthorizationID |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1                    | G1        | AUTH1             |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2                    | G2        | AUTH1             |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| 3                    | G1        | AUTH2             |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| 4                    | G3        | AUTH1             |
+----------------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

**MemberGroup**

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| MemberGroupID | FKGroupID | FKMemberID |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 1             | G1        | 1          |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 2             | G2        | 1          |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 3             | G4        | 2          |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| 4             | G4        | 3          |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

I need to get all the users, who have **Send** authorization. how can I write a join query to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select M.name, A.Authorization
FROM Authorization A INNER JOIN GroupAuthorization GA 
ON A.AuthorizationID = GA.FkAuthorizationID
INNER JOIN MemberGroup MG 
ON MG.FKGroupID  = GA.FKGroupID 
INNER JOIN Memeber M ON M.MemberID  = MG.FKMemberID 
where A.AuthorizationName  = 'Send'
```